Вызов javascript функции в html странице через python
Всем бобра! Сразу к делу.
Я пилю свой кастом-виджет донатов для OBS. У меня уже есть рабочий python код, который отлавливает приход донатов на DonationAlerts. Главная задача - отображать донаты, только при определённых условиях в зависимости от стрима (сам нажму кнопку когда можно отображать донат, а когда надо ставить в очередь).
Мне нужно следующее:

Локальный html со стандартным стилем доната (gif, имя, сообщение и тд)
Внутри javascript вызывающий отображение этого доната, принимает все нужные данные (имя, сообщение и тд)
Как-то вызывать javascript функцию отображения доната из python скрипта когда уже пора.

Думаю, с первыми двумя пунктами разберусь сам. А вот ответ на третий пункт я так и не нашёл.
Как вызвать javascript функцию в html странице через python?
Или может я не туда копаю и есть способ проще и лучше, сразу через python всё решить?
Заранее спасибо!

Как вызвать javascript функцию в html странице через python? - сам по себе сервер не может "влиять" на уже загруженную страницу на клиенте. А вот клиет может взаимодействовать с сервером. Как вариант: - клиент, с некой периодичностью, опрашивает сервер http-запросом на тему "а не случилось ли чего?". - Клиент имеет "сокетное" соединение с сервером, т.о. они могут обмениваться сообщениями. Т.е. теперь и сервер может что-то отправить клиенту, если возникла такая надобность.

То есть нужен некий скрипт в html, который будет раз в n-секунд смотреть обновление?
Я кстати узнал что в html можно использовать python скрипт, то есть можно обойти вообще js.
<script type="text/python" src="my_script.py"></script>

html работает на клиенте, python на сервере. Так что нужна постоянная связь клиента и сервера. К уже описанным вариантам(дергание сервера раз в N минут и сокета) есть еще технология SSE
